# What does this shortened code mean in C (inside int_wall function)

Tags: c

This is the part of MAZE algorithm. The shortened part of this code which is in the function is not so clear. Is my suggestion correct?

```
...
#define UP 1
#define RIGHT 2
#define DOWN 4
#define LEFT 8
...
int wall_ahead(int m[MAZE_SIZE][MAZE_SIZE], int x, int y, int dir){
    x = (dir == LEFT) ? --x :
        (dir == RIGHT) ? ++x : x;
    y = (dir == UP) ? --y :
        (dir == DOWN) ? ++y : y;

    return m[x][y];
}
```

My Suggestion is:

```
if(dir == LEFT){
    x -= 1;
    if(dir==RIGHT){
       x += 1;
    } else {
        x = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put an `else` before the second `if`.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: `x -= x`? That's not what `--x` means. Perhaps `x -= 1`.

Comment: My question is that: Is my suggestion correct? Thanks

Comment: Put your question [inside your question](edit), not in a comment.

Comment: No, your suggestion is not correct. Have you tried it for various inputs, and compared the outcomes? You could write a simple program that compares the two versions for just values of `x`.

Comment: Note that the actual posted example isn't syntactically correct and will not compile. It also doesn't handle the case where the input `x` value is `0` and the direction if `LEFT`.

Comment: The `UP,RIGHT,DOWN,LEFT` definitions don't make sense. They seem to be bit-wise flags (e.g. `if (dir & UP) ...`), but a user cannot turn up and down nor left and right at the same time.

Comment: @barakmanos though it's not a bad idea to implement it that way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a switch statement, like this:

```
switch (dir) {
case UP:
    --y; break;
case DOWN:
    ++y; break;
case LEFT:
    --x; break;
case RIGHT:
    ++x; break;
}
```

Doing the assignments like the original listing is plain wrong, these prefix operators already modify the value.

OTOH, it seems `UP` and `DOWN` would be  mutually exclusive, but not to `RIGHT` and `LEFT`  and the same applies the other way around, so this would be more correct:

```
x += !!(dir & DOWN) - !!(dir & UP);
y += !!(dir & RIGHT) - !!(dir & LEFT);
```

Also, not so important, but there are a couple of typos in the original listing... check out those... and you need to give it the dimensions of the array, otherwise the address calculation can't be done by the compiler.

Comment: Thank you that was what I was looking for.

Comment: Check out the edit about going in diagonal directions.

Comment: 1. It doesn't make since to change the value of an argument passed by value (as OP does in his/her code, which you should point out IMO). 2. Your `switch/case` does not allow a combination of `UP/RIGHT`, `UP/LEFT`, etc.

Comment: @barakmanos point 1) still does make sense, the values are used, and it's common practice to do it that way. point 2) addressed before your comment kicked in, but the original listing of code didn't handle the case since the tests were using the == operator.

Comment: @IsmaelLuceno: Yes, I agree about the original code. In any case, those definitions don't make much sense, as it appears as if they were meant to be used as bit-wise flags, yet they are not (see my comment to the question).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(dir == LEFT){
    x -= 1;
    if(dir==RIGHT){
       x += 1
    } else {
        x = x;
    }
}
```

is not correct. It does not do what the first code block does.

It needs to be:

```
if(dir == LEFT){
    x -= 1;
}
else if(dir==RIGHT){
    x += 1
}
```

The meaning of the code is simpler to follow now.

If `dir` is `LEFT`, decrement `x` by 1.
   If `dir` is `RIGHT`, increment `x` by 1.
   Else don't do anything with `x`.

Meaning of the rest of the code in the first code block:

If `dir` is `UP`, decrement `y` by 1.
   If `dir` is `DOWN`, increment `y` by 1.
   Else don't do anything with `y`.